Buck converter Sim not working
I am having some issues getting a simulation of a buck converter I've been trying to design to work. For some reason the op amp (circled in Red) isn't seeing any voltage on either of its inputs (both are in the low milivolt range), neither from the saw-tooth generator or the feedback circuit. I was hoping that like this it would act as a comparator so that it can send a PWM signal to the MOSFET.

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong, any tips on what I can do to go in the right direction to solve this would be much appreciated. (I am still learning op amps at the moment so haven't quite gotten the hang of them yet)


I am not too sure what I am doing wrong, any tips on what I can do to
go in the right direction to solve this would be much appreciated.

Following your relaxation amplifier (top left) you have an integrator that cannot possibly work without a high value resistor in parallel with the feedback capacitor.
There may be other problems but this one sticks out.
Tip of the day: ensure your schematic has reference designators visible.
